iOS generating invalid signature with SecureEnclave protected key pair
I'm facing an issue with 0.01% of user base having problems generating signature. Basically, they are able to generate key pair but the resulting signature is invalid when validated with the public key.
The signature is being created with the following code.
  @objc public func signData(
    _ text: String,
    resolver resolve: RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
    rejecter reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock
  ) -> Void {
    guard let privateKey = self.getPrivateKey() else {
      reject(nil, "error fetching private key", nil)
      return
    }

    let data =  text.data(using: .utf8)!

    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    let signature = SecKeyCreateSignature(privateKey, .ecdsaSignatureMessageX962SHA256, data as CFData, &error) as Data?
    if error != nil {
      reject(nil, "Error in creating signature", nil)
      return
    }
    
    resolve(signature!.base64EncodedString())
  }

The keypair is generated as follows:
  @objc public func generateKeyPair(
    _ resolve: RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
    rejecter reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock
  ) -> Void {
    let access = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(
      kCFAllocatorDefault,
      kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly,
      .privateKeyUsage,
      nil)!

    let attributes: NSDictionary = [
      kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
      kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: 256,
      kSecAttrTokenID: kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave, // Enable secure enclave
      kSecPrivateKeyAttrs: [
        kSecAttrAccessible: kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly, // Do not share across devices with same appleid
        kSecAttrIsPermanent: true,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag: privateKeyTag,
        kSecAttrAccessControl: access
      ],
      kSecPublicKeyAttrs: [
        kSecAttrAccessible: kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly, // Do not share across devices with same appleid
        kSecAttrIsPermanent: true,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag: publicKeyTag,
      ]
    ]
    
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    guard let privateKey = SecKeyCreateRandomKey(attributes, &error) else {
      reject(nil, "error creating private key", error!.takeRetainedValue() as Error)
      return
    }
    
    let publicKey = SecKeyCopyPublicKey(privateKey)
    if publicKey == nil {
      reject(nil, "error creating public key", nil)
      return
    }

    resolve(self.PEMFormattedPublicKey(key: publicKey!))
  }

  private func PEMFormattedPublicKey(key: SecKey) -> String? {
    guard let publicKeyData = self.dataForKey(key: key) else {
      return nil
    }
    
    // ans1 headers format. From https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEo0WcFrFClvBE8iZ1Gdlj-mTgZoJWMNE3kDKTfRny2iaguwuSYxo-jCnXqzkR-kyFK9CR3D-pypD1sGb1BnfWAA
    // Requred for 256 EC keys
    let ecHeader: [UInt8] = [
        0x30, 0x59, // Sequence
        0x30, 0x13, // Algorithm identifier
        0x06, 0x07, 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0xCE, 0x3D, 0x02, 0x01, // (ANSI X9.62 public key type)
        0x06, 0x08, 0x2A, 0x86, 0x48, 0xCE, 0x3D, 0x03, 0x01, // (ANSI X9.62 named elliptic curve)
        0x07, 0x03, 0x42, 0x00 // bit headers
    ]

    var asn1 = Data()
    asn1.append(Data(ecHeader))
    asn1.append(publicKeyData as Data)
    
    let encoded = asn1.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
    let pemString = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n\(encoded)\r\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n"
    
    return pemString
  }

And in the backend service, the check is made with the following code:
 const publicKey = Buffer.from(publicKeyB64, 'base64').toString('utf-8');
 const key = {
   key: publicKey,
 };
 const verifier = createVerify('SHA256');
 verifier.update(challenge);

 return verifier.verify(key, digest, 'base64');

This is strange since is only happening to a very few users. iOS versions ranging from 17 to 18.1.
Sample of corrupted digest
challenge: ac13288a-3ef7-4eb8-9198-5cb7f3a18665
signature: MEUCIEQMq6unQLES+vBMhalDG0ZxTX9TNWukb63Qqd7W4ReRAiEAyqTwMMQC/HkU4AbLmwbBTm6DBFDpA8yo+3Cigg0H0VA=
publicKeyB64: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBQVUJMSUMgS0VZLS0tLS0NCk1Ga3dFd1lIS29aSXpqMENBUVlJS29aSXpqMERBUWNEUWdBRXJENjNrSXdRaC83bVNia1R1QllUUEJtSGdOVmwNCnJueE4rNGVER2pHSDNRZmdVaGhKNlZYTjVSWTZhVW9iRjd3MjdFQXMwZ0JHaTdjOXdPdndQbmhxNEE9PQ0KLS0tLS1FTkQgUFVCTElDIEtFWS0tLS0tDQo=

Can you post a test key pair and a corrupted signature?

Sure, just added!

The signature looks OK. I thought that a sporadic format error might be the cause. Are you sure that the data is consistent, i.e. that the signature and message belong together and that the public key belongs to the private key used to create the signature?

Make sense... I added a snippet showing how I transform the public key to PEM format. Maybe it is related to this function.
The keys/challenge/digest are correlated and are from genuine users.

I think the problem is something related to sporadic format error. Some users randomly send correct signature data eventually. But there are some devices that keep sending invalid signatures.

I can't recognize a format error in the posted siganture. A description of the ASN.1/DER format can be found here in the first section. Perhaps the data is inconsistent (message/signature/private/public key). I don't know your environment, but maybe the data is mixed up somewhere (e.g. an old public key is used etc.). However, if the library provides really this posted data, this may indicate a bug such that an incorrect signature is generated or an inappropriate public key is provided.

You should add error handling whenever you call a Sec* function. It's tedious but inevitable.

Have you tried using SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation() to obtain a representation of the public key? In this case, it is a slightly different format (ANSI X9.63), which returns an uncompressed version of the key, i.e. 04 || X || Y.  The server would also need to be able to recognise it. It's ANSI X9.63, so it should handle it. IMHO, it's probably better to use a system function than manually encoding it.

Also, you may check if after generation of the key-pair, and after a new release of the app, when fetching the public key, it is again ensured you get the correctly associated public key for the private key, and don't refer to an older private key, or an older private key is accidentally used, etc.

@CouchDeveloper I'll try that. I'm tending to use P256.Signing.PublicKey(x963Representation: publicKeyData) to encode the public key to X9.63 format.

You might also check the kSecAttrAccessible  value of the private key. You have two conflicting values, one is set in the access control, the other directly in kSecPrivateKeyAttrs.  Strictly, there can be only one value. The documentation is very vague about it, but my guess is, that the value defined in the access control value overrides a value for attribute kSecAttrAccessible, when set. You might just remove it.
